# Trying to upload and align CSV, Video and audio file into Matlab

Tags: matlab, csv, audio, video

Hi  I am relatively new to Matlab and need to analyze data for a research project. Basically I am importing .csv file into matlab as well as a video and audio file in order to see if I can find a correlation. I've successfully imported the csv file but I am unable to import video and audio. Furthermore once I have uploaded it into matlab I need to align the data from the CSV file and audio and video.

Answer (score 0):

Matlab has several built-in utilities for this.
Try using the `VideoReader` and `audioread` to import your video and audio respectively. You can look at the Matlab documentation for each of these functions for more information on their properties.

The last part of your question is too vague. You need to specify what format the data from the CSV is in, what its relationship to the video is, and what kind of alignment you want.

Comment: So when i use VideoReader it says this : Error using VideoReader/errorIfTextFormat (line 503)
The filename specified is a text file. Use edit instead of
VideoReader.

Error in VideoReader/init (line 613)
            VideoReader.errorIfTextFormat(fullName);

Error in VideoReader (line 172)
            obj.init(fileName);    I presume this means the file did not upload correctly even though it is in mp4 format. As for aligning the data essentially I have someones heart rate and ecg and I want to align that with the video and audio file corresponding to this information.

Comment: This is a known issue with these functions. Here is the link to the bug report and the suggested work-around.

http://www.mathworks.com/support/bugreports/1246784

As for aligning your data. You should be able to use the time stamps on the data and match them to the time stamps/frame count in the video and audio files

Comment: Do you know if this is the case with just ubuntu or OSX as well?

Comment: I don't have any problem with the VideoReader reading .mp4 in OS X El Capitan 10.11.5 and MatLab 2016a. 
Based on the error you got, I would suggest re-saving your video file to make sure that it is the correct format--I usually use .mp4 or .mov-- instead of a text file. 
Additionally, make sure that there is not another file of the same name before your file in the same path. If this is the issue, you can get around it by changing your working directory or including the entire path in the VideoReader object.

Comment: I got it to work and am able to assess the videos frame by frame but there is no time stamp on the videos. Would I need the video to have a time stamp initially or is there something that I can include in the code that will allow me to get the time stamp.

Comment: The VideoReader handle returns the duration of the video and the frame rate so you should be able to determine the time from that. It was just a suggestion since you didn't post any of your CSV data. You will have to find the method that works best for what you are doing